# navigationController popViewController not working perfect

Tags: ios, xcode6, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a small issue. When i click on back button it goes to previous page.

```
- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {
    testingViewClicked = @"NO";
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It works fine. When i click on refresh button in the same page view is loaded. After that when i click on back button it goes to before previous page. But here i want previous page not before previous page.

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender {

   [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"orderViewController"];
   [self viewDidLoad];
   fDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"fromDateOrderView"]];
   NSLog(@"from date here %@", fDate);
   [self orderFuntionCalling];
```

}

This is what i am done in refresh button. It will works perfect in simulator iOS 7 & 8. When i run in a device it shows this bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put what you have in viewDidLoad somewhere else and call that instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: i done this but not working perfect @Arbitur

Comment: where are you calling it from?

Comment: instead of viewDidLoad i am calling [self orderViewLoad]; @Arbitur

Comment: You must be doing something to make popViewController execitr twice, if you add this button or tag gesture that calls that function when reload you mustve added it twice without removing the old one

Comment: Please post orderViewDidLoad

Comment: http://pastie.org/9879921 see this @Arbitur

Comment: Add a NSLog in backToHome to check wether it gets called twice or not, and also comment out the orderViewDidLoad in refreshButton to check if it still occurs and do the same with orderFuntionCalling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70031/discussion-between-vishnu-and-arbitur).

Comment: log prints two times @Arbitur

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Simply setting user interaction

```
- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {
   _homeButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   testingViewClicked = @"NO";
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```